# JQuery Select2 access processResults mapping from outside its function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2

I'm using [select2](https://select2.github.io) JQuery plugin to implement an autocomplete input-like element backed by a json endpoint, in this select2 input, I want the user can also create new objects into the same element by just giving them names or using the available on the endpoint.

My problem is that I need to access the processed 'data' mapping generated on 'processResults' key *outside* its function, actually inside the createTag function, I'm not sure if I need to use some JQuery method to access the result or control it using some global variable.
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<p>
    <select class="js-example-tags form-control" multiple="multiple"></select>
</p>
```

JS:

```
var $tags = $(".js-example-tags");
    var responsejson;
    $.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/compat/matcher'], function(oldMatcher) {
        $tags.select2({
            ajax: {
                data: function(params) {
                    var unicode = "\uf8ff";
                    var startAt = '"' + params.term + '"';
                    var endAt = '"' + params.term + unicode + '"';
                    var query = {
                        orderBy: "\"lowerCaseName\"",
                        startAt: startAt.toLowerCase(),
                        endAt: endAt.toLowerCase(),
                        print: "\"pretty\""
                    };
                    // Query paramters will be ?search=[term]&page=[page]
                    return query;
                },
                url: 'https://someappname.firebaseio.com/substancies.json?',
                processResults: function(data, key) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function(obj, key) {
                            responsejson = {
                                id: key,
                                lower: obj.lowerCaseName,
                                text: obj.commonName
                            };
                            return responsejson;
                        })
                    };
                }
            },
            tags: true,
            createTag: function(params) {
                if (responsejson !== undefined) {
                    console.log("Oppa");
                }
                var term = $.trim(params.term);
                if (term === "") {
                    return null;
                }

                var optionsMatch = false;
                var arrValue = $(".js-example-tags").select2('data');

                for (var i = 0; i < arrValue.length; i++) {
                    var var1 = arrValue[i].lower;
                    var var2 = term.toLowerCase();
                    if (term.toLowerCase() === arrValue[i].lower) {
                        optionsMatch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (optionsMatch) {
                    return null;
                }
                return {
                    id: -1,
                    text: term
                };
            },
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            tokenSeparators: [','],
            casesensitive: false
        });
    });
```

Comment: I believe createTag is actually called before the AJAX request is sent, otherwise you should just be able to set the result of processResults to another variable before returning them.

Comment: Yeah, I did exactly that way, but I wasn't sure if it is the elegant way of doing it..